# Microtypography status in LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, microtype

According to this table from the [`microtype` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf), the current support of microtypography in the TeX engines is as follows:

[image]

Nevertheless, TeX.SX is full of LuaTeX workarounds in specific cases for the lack of “extra kerning” and “extra spacing” options in `microtype` for LuaTeX. Does that mean that all of these “missing” features are actually completely supported in LuaTeX after all, using a few workarounds? In 2022, may we regard the microtypography support in LuaTeX as being as complete as in pdfTeX?

Comment: It seems that you can get some (most?) of those features with `fontspec`, so it's probably interesting to widen your question to include other microtypography solutions than `microtype` (sorry, not at home right now, I'll try to find links later today).

Comment: @Miyase Actually, my question intentionally doesn’t limit itself to the microtypographic solutions in `microtype`. It only uses the table from the `microtype` manual as a general guideline for the status of microtypography in the LuaTeX engine itself.

Comment: it is probably possible to reimplement the kerning and spacing features in luatex, using lua code instead of the pdftex primitives. However, this hasn't been done for microtype, which is what the table represents.

Comment: As you can see from the table, these data are heavily outdated. It is certainly possible to achieve the “Kerning” and “Spacing” features in LuaTeX, but `microtype` does not implement this.

Comment: I recently learned of `lua-widow-control` package, which solves an related problem by applying some further hacks in Lua. It seems to use `microtype`.